# Scheduling a ride with Uber

Tags: uber

I would like to schedule a ride with Uber a few days in advance. The city where the ride is going to take place is in a different time zone than where I am currently located. If I need a ride at 18:00 according to the local time of my destination, do I need to input 18:00 or what 18:00 corresponds to in the local time of my current location?

Comment: A suggestion: please make sure you know what "scheduling a ride" with Uber means. I met someone who assumed it was like booking a taxi - but it is not. It is more like an alarm "schedule uber ride" set on your phone 15 minutes before the ride. https://help.uber.com/h/63165ec1-0910-409e-972f-0b8d8df1a605 - and personally I found this functionality being utterly useless as you're still hit with surge charges, and there's no guarantee you'd get a ride.

Comment: @GeorgeY. +1 that is very much an answer; please add it, and I'll upvote.

Comment: I made the trip in the question and scheduling is based on the local time of the city where the ride is going to take place.

Answer (score 7):

Moved from the comment:

Before doing so, please make sure you know what "scheduling a ride" with Uber means. I met someone who assumed it was like booking a taxi - but it is not. It is more like an alarm "schedule uber ride" set on your phone 15 minutes before the ride, which launches an app and requests Uber on your behalf 15 minutes before the ride.

Personally I found this functionality being utterly useless, because it does not protect you from surge charges (will you still ride if it is a 4x surge?), and there's no guarantee you'd get a car.

[Please see the relevant help section on Uber web site](http://help.uber.com/h/63165ec1-0910-409e-972f-0b8d8df1a605)

Comment: This is true, but does not actually answer the question.

Comment: Also, I'm a reasonably frequent user of scheduled Uber rides simply for the convenience. My last one was at 5:15 AM, meaning I didn't have to wake up a few min earlier to tap away at the app.

Comment: What if once you wake up a few minutes later, you found that no ride is available, or see a 4x surge? I'm just curious, as couple times I tried this, it was exactly my experience.

Comment: I live in a part of town where neither is ever a problem.  By contrast, I have been stood up by prebooked regular taxis. YMMV.